# How to disable swipe effect in owl carousel 2?

Tags: jquery, slider, fadein, owl-carousel-2

I need to disable swipe effect on [owl carousel 2](http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) and add only fadeIn effect. How is it possible ?

I have tried this code but no luck at all.

```
animateOut: 'fadeIn',
animateIn: 'fadeout',
nav:true,
```

Thanks

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle for demo http://jsfiddle.net/sunilkjt/eoh95qvq/

Answer (score 7):

```
mouseDrag: false,
touchDrag: false
```

Comment: It could be helpful to explain a bit more why changing these properties would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some css see [here](http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html)

> fadeOut value is the only built-in CSS animate style. However there are tons of additional CSS animations that you can use in Owl. Simply download [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library and you are ready to extend Owl with new fancy transitions.

So if you want to add just fade effect you need to add some css like this.

```
.animated {
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.owl-item.animated {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I have added the css but there's no fade effect.

Comment: try by adding animate css

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.1/animate.min.css"> have added this cdn but no luck

Comment: can you make fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all the effects just add this

```
animateIn: 'false',
```

and it will remove it.
now if you want to add fade-in or fade-out effect only or both add this code

```
animateOut: 'fadeOut', // for fade out only 
// add both if you want both effect
animateIn: 'fadeIn', //for fade in only
```

Comment: That's not what he asked.